# syntax error near unexpected token `|' Perl code

Tags: perl, shell, fedora

I am trying to execute this in my perl script

```
my $command = `ps -p  $pidnumber |  wc -l`;
```

but when I run the script it show me something like this:

sh: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `|'

sh: -c: line 1: ` | wc -l'

Which would it may to be the error?

Comment: Where is $pidnumber coming from?  Might it have a newline appended to it?

Answer (score 1):

Does `$pidnumber` end with a new line? See the [`chomp`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#chomp) function.

Answer (score 1):

try print before execute the command, because `$pidnumber` may have something strange:

```
my $command_str = "ps -p  $pidnumber |  wc -l";
print $command_str, "\n";
my $command = qx!$command_str!;
```

as @mob said, use chomp if newline appears in the print sentence.

Comment: `use Data::Dumper; local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print(Dumper($command_str));` for more useful at finding oddities, especially trailing newlines.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other answers that an extra newline before the pipe is quite possibly the cause

But the command doesn't really need the pipe!

force the quoted command to return it's value as a list and then get the length of the list and you've got the wc -l "line count"

```
my $command_str = "ps -p  $pidnumber";
my $linecount = () = qx!$command_str!;
```